# Managing models relations in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, orm, angularjs

how you manage models relations with AngularJS? It is very easy in Ember, but how to deal with it in AngularJS and not produce bunch of messy code?

Comment: Can you give some example? In AngularJS you manipulate with javascript objects, so you can directly reference other objects and then `$watch` them (don't forget to set `true` to second parameter). Also there is Dependency injection so you can inject depended objects (note `value` method of module)

Answer (score 2):

I use https://github.com/klederson/ModelCore/ it's very simple and easy to use

```
var ExampleApp = angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ModelCore']); //injecting ModelCore

ExampleApp.factory("Users",function(ModelCore) {
  return ModelCore.instance({
    $type : "Users", //Define the Object type
    $pkField : "idUser", //Define the Object primary key
    $settings : {
      urls : {
        base : "http://myapi.com/users/:idUser",
      }
    },
    $myCustomMethod : function(info) { //yes you can create and apply your own custom methods
        console.log(info);
    }
  });
});
```

And then i just need to inject into my controller and use it

```
function MainCrtl($scope, Users) {
  //Setup a model to example a $find() call
  $scope.AllUsers = new Users();

  //Get All Users from the API
  $scope.AllUsers.$find().success(function() {
    var current;
    while(current = $scope.AllUsers.$fetch()) { //fetching on masters object
      console.log("Fetched Data into Master Object",$scope.AllUsers.$toObject()) //reading fetched from master
      //or just get the fetched object itself
      console.log("Real fetched Object",current.$toObject())
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't have a "data store" layer like ember-data, but you can integrate any existing ORM if you'd like to - [What options are available for client-side JavaScript ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786307/which-javascript-orm-to-use)