# change Content-type to "application/json" POST method, RESTful API

Tags: angularjs

I am new at AngularJS and I needed your help.

All I need just need is to POST my json to the API and recieve the proper response.

Here's my JSON where i don't know where to code this.

**JSON**

```
{ 
    "userId"      :"testAgent2",
    "token"       :"testAgent2",
    "terminalInfo":"test2",
    "forceLogin"  :"false"
}
```

NOT SURE IF I'm doing this right.

**CONTROLLER.JS**

```
function UserLoginCtrl($scope, UserLoginResource) {
    //Save a new userLogin
    $scope.loginUser = function() {
        var loggedin = false;
        var uUsername = $scope.userUsername;
        var uPassword = $scope.userPassword;
        var uforcelogin = 'true';

        UserLoginResource.save();
    }
}
```

**SERVICES.JS**

```
angular.module('UserLoginModule', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('UserLoginResource', function($resource, $http) {
        $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json"; //NOT WORKING

        return $resource('http://123.123.123.123\\:1234/SOME/LOCATION/THERE', {}, {
            save: { 
                method:'POST', 
                headers: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}] 
            } //NOT WORKING EITHER
        });
    });
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<html ng-app>

<head>
<script src="js/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="UserLoginCtrl">
  
<form class="form-horizontal" name="form-horizontal" ng-submit="loginUser();">

<div class="button-login">

<!-- start: button-login -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>

</div>

</form>


</body>   


</html>
```

I kept on getting a response like Unsupported Media Type. I don't know, what else to do.

Comment: by default content type is application/json so no need to override it please check your json format is correct or not please monitor network tab in chrome so see it proper json is being sent over the network

Comment: I did an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708804/managing-models-relations-in-angular/17055281#17055281 please check if it help you.

Comment: I think `$http.defaults.useXDomain` setting is a myth, it doesn't exist in the source code! https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/angular/kl2BVOubG4I

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Posting a JSON object is quite easy in Angular. All you need to do is the following:

**Create a Javascript Object**

I'll use your exact properties from your code.

```
var postObject = new Object();
postObject.userId = "testAgent2";
postObject.token = "testAgent2";
postObject.terminalInfo = "test2";
postObject.forceLogin = "false";
```

**Post the object to the API**

To post an object to an API you merely need a simple $http.post function. See below:

```
$http.post("/path/to/api/", postObject).success(function(data){
    //Callback function here.
    //"data" is the response from the server.
});
```

Since JSON is the default method of posting to an API, there's no need to reset that. See [this link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#shortcutmethods) on $http shortcuts for more information.

With regards to your code specifically, try changing your save method to include this simple post method.

Comment: Good day sir, so what you mean is i'm going to change the line with $resource and change it to $http?

Comment: Yes, that whole return portion can be replaced with this much simpler call. How you'll integrate that into your project is up to you.

Comment: I can't get it working. I keep getting the following error in the console:

POST http://localhost:49653/api/warehouses/ 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

I think it has to do with application/json at the AngularJS end and application/x-www-form-urlencoded at the ASP.NET WebAPI end.

It works this way:
data: "id=3&name=prueba&location=madrid",
headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

I would like to be able to get json at the WebAPI end, though. Any further help?

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you are able to use one of the more recent "unstable" releases, the correct syntax to change the header is.

```
app.factory('BarService', function ($resource) {
var BarService = $resource('/foo/api/bars/:id', {}, {    
    'delete': {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
});
 return BarService;
});
```

I find the $resource service is a tremendously powerful tool for building applications and has matured to a point that you do not need to fall back to $http as much.  Plus its active record like patterns are damn convenient.

Comment: How can I pass to 'delete' an object to send in the request body?

Comment: Hi @brescia123, "usually" the http method itself would indicate the desired action you would like to achieve, as shown above for DELETES. If you are unable to call/expose the DELETE method then its not unheard of to pass in a request object that would contain both the object and the desired action: {'action' : 'delete', {'target': myObj}} but I am not a fan of this since it would not conform to the generally accepted principals of RESTful services.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to set 'Content-Type': 'application/json' is setting a transformRequest function for the save action.

```
angular.module('NoteWrangler')
.factory('NoteNgResource', function NoteNgResourceFactory($resource) {

    // https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

    return $resource("./php/notes/:id", {}, {
        save : { // redefine save action defaults
            method : 'POST',
            url : "./php/notes", // I dont want the id in the url
            transformRequest: function(data, headers){
                console.log(headers);
                headers = angular.extend({}, headers, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                console.log(headers);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(angular.toJson(data));
                return angular.toJson(data); // this will go in the body request
            }               
        }
    });
});
```

It seems there isn't a method to clear query parameters, the request will have both...