# AngularJS $resource save() causes HTTP Error 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angular-resource

I am using Angular 1.2-RC2 (also tried 1.0.8 and 1.1.x) and the ngResource module. The backend is a Spring WebMVC application.

```
angular.module("dox", ['ngResource'])

.controller('SettingsController', function ($scope, Settings) {
    $scope.settings = Settings.query();

    $scope.save = function () {
        Settings.save();
    };
})

.factory('Settings', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/v1/settings/:settingId', {settingId: '@id'}, {
        'save': {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Whenever the save() method on the Settings class gets called the frontend receives a HTTP 415 (Unsupported media type). The reason is that AngularJS send the POST request using the following content type:

```
Content type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
```

but the backend expects

```
Content type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

According the [API docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) it should be possible to override the header but my settings are somehow ignored. I seems that this is a common problem and as a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211443/angularjs-change-content-type-to-application-json-post-method-restful-api) there are many recommendation to use $http.post instead of $resource.

Can you give me any hint how to solve this content type problem using the $resource service?

Please find the backend controller code [here](https://github.com/saw303/dox/blob/angularjs/web/src/main/java/ch/silviowangler/dox/web/rest/RestSettingsController.java#L71).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin Stone pushed me to the right direction. Thank you!

Since query() returns an array and save() is meant to save only one item of that array at the same time I had to reimplement the save() stuff [differently](https://github.com/saw303/dox/blob/833b529a2b096ab0bb5ed0c3f712cf2bc52d36e6/web/src/main/webapp/js/dox/settings.js#L11).

```
$scope.save = function () {    
   angular.forEach($scope.settings, function (value, key) {                    
      value.$save();
   });
};
```

Done! Again thank you for your hints and help

Comment: Any reason you're not using the instance method and calling `value.$save()` instead of the class-level `Settings.save()` inside the `forEach` loop?  I think it would help you avoid these issues if you treat these resource instances as objects instead of just data containers.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're overriding a built-in `$save` method, so you can just omit the `save:` part (see [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L282)).  If you do define additional HTTP methods that aren't built-in, you can update the `$httpProvider` like so (this is to add the `patch` method):

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason why I override the save method is that when I used the standard configuration (which looks correct and is what I wanted) also sends the request as text/plain instead of application/json. Is it a problem to call save on an array since Settings is an array (retrieved by query()) or why does AngularJS decide to use text/plain?