# How to get JSON in Java REST / AngularJS frontend

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jakarta-ee

Can someone please help me how to get a JSON String in a Webservice. I's sending JSON to my /api/register that looks like:

```
{"name":"MyName","surname":"MySurename","email":"mail@asd.de","street":"MyStreet","number":"3","zip":"12345","city":"myCity","pass":"myPassword"}
```

Here is my register.java file:

```
@Path("/register")
@Stateless
public class RegisterWS {

    @EJB
    UserBS userBS;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void createUser(){

        // code to get data from json

        userBS.createUser(name, surename, email, adress, number, zip, city, password);

    }
}
```

My AngularJS Controller and Service. The Data comes from a form, that is parsed to a JSON object.

```
app.service('RegisterService', function ($http) {

    return {        

        registerUser : function(user) {

            $http.post('http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/register')
                    .success(function (user) {
                        return user;
                    })
                    .error(function (data) {
                        // failed

                    });
        }

    }

});

app.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, RegisterService) {

    $scope.register = function(){
        RegisterService.registerUser(angular.toJson($scope.user));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a POJO, which maps to the received JSON object, for example a `User` class. In this case this would be a very simple Java Bean, with mostly `String` properties for each field in the JSON.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {
    String name;
    String surname;
    String email;
    String street;
    Integer number;
    String zip;
    String city;
    String pass;
}
```

Of course you would use private fields, with getters and setters, but I did not want to add clutter. By the way the `@XmlRootElement` is a JAXB annotation, and JAX-RS uses JAXB internally.

After you have this, you just need to change your method like this

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void createUser(User user) {
    ...
}
```

You should not need to change anything on the AngularJS side, as the default for the `$http.post` method is JSON communication.

Comment: I have a POJO, just didnt put the @XmlRootElement on top of it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For your Java code, you have to add a User POJO, I dont know if you will use some persistence API or not, so the user POJO must implement serializable to output user object as JSON.

Here's a an example of REST app with EJB ... : http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/rest-on-ejb/README.html

For your client app, you need to specify the content type : `"Content-Type" = "application/json"`

See this questions: [change Content-type to "application/json" POST method, RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211443/change-content-type-to-application-json-post-method-restful-api)