# unsupported media type web api post

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

i am using angularjs to post the data created webapi. its working on my local system, but when i uploaded on server its not working and returning error, unsupported media type. please help me how to fix this.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller("QueryControllerController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.submit = function () {
        if ($scope.QueryDescription) {
            var product = {
                "QueryDescription": $scope.QueryDescription,
                "CategoryID": $scope.CategoryID

            }
            $http.post('/api/querycontroller', JSON.stringify(product)).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('Added Successfully' + headers);
                $('#formusers')[0].reset();
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(status + ", " + data + ", " + headers + "," + config);
            });
        }
    };

}
);
```

my api controller code is :

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Query))]

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Query Services)
    {

        Services.CommunityID = UserStatus.GetUserID(User.Identity.Name);
        Services = repository.Add(Services);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Query>(HttpStatusCode.Created, Services);
        string uri = Url.Route(null, new { id = Services.QueryID });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, uri);

        return response;

    }
```

When I try to post, I get Unsupported Media Type response.:

```
  "Message": "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported   for this resource."
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the [ResponseType(typeof(Query))] and use a ViewModel class as a parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]ProductViewModel product)
{
```

Also...

Try the approach (in the agunlar controller) suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267724/john as the answer to this post:
[change Content-type to "application/json" POST method, RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211443/change-content-type-to-application-json-post-method-restful-api)

> Posting a JSON object is quite easy in Angular. All you need to do is the following:
>
> Create a Javascript Object
>
> I'll use your exact properties from your code.

```
var postObject = new Object();
postObject.userId = "testAgent2";
postObject.token = "testAgent2";
postObject.terminalInfo = "test2";
postObject.forceLogin = "false";
Post the object to the API
```

> To post an object to an API you merely need a simple $http.post
>   function. See below:

```
$http.post("/path/to/api/", postObject).success(function(data){
    //Callback function here.
    //"data" is the response from the server.
});
```

> Since JSON is the default method of posting to an API, there's no need
>   to reset that. See this link on $http shortcuts for more information.
>
> With regards to your code specifically, try changing your save method
>   to include this simple post method.