# Posting form data in Angular 4 is received in Django as bytes

Tags: python, django, angular

I am trying to build a full stack web app using Angular 4 on the front end and Django on the backend. I created a reactive form in Angular, which I submit to a backend API that is linked in Django urls.py. The full code is on my GitHub repo: https://github.com/shivkiyer/django-angular

The Angular component code has:

```
newCompanyForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  'name': this.name,
  'headquarters': this.headquarters,
  'address': this.address,
  'company_website': this.company_website,
  'established_year': this.established_year
});


addCompany() {
  console.log(this.newCompanyForm.value);
  this.http.post(this.apiBaseURL + 'new-company',
            JSON.stringify(this.newCompanyForm.value)).subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log(response);
    },
    errors => {
      console.log(errors);
    }
  );
}
```

Where addCompany() is called with the ngSubmit of the form. The Angular form is a mirror image of the Django model which is:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='Google', max_length=200)
    headquarters = models.CharField(default='San Jose, California', max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(default='123 River Drive, San Jose, California', \
                max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    company_website = models.URLField(default='http://www.google.com', \
                blank=True, null=True)
    established_year = models.IntegerField(default=2000, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + " in " + str(self.headquarters)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.name) + " in " + str(self.headquarters)
```

I have created a simple class based view to receive the form data:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class NewCompany(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Hello world"})

    def post(self, request):
        new_company_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        new_company = Company(**new_company_data)
        new_company.save()
        return HttpResponse("Done");
```

For now I am not bothering with CSRF token and am also running the Angular and Django servers separately. The problem is the post data is appearing in Django as a byte string and only in request.body. request.POST is . I used JSON.stringify() only to convert it into JSON embedded inside a string. To insert it into a model instance, I used decode and then json.loads() to convert it to JSON data.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to extract the POST data in a more convenient manner. I used to use Django Templates before but since I learned Angular 4, I am trying to mix them.

Comment: I think you may be doing it wrong from angular... https://stackoverflow.com/a/17224360/5412392

Your using a form rather than an object? But I'm not super familiar with angular...I would at least check that the request Django is receiving has `Content-Type`: `application/json`.

Comment: I tried checking out the content_type but it gives me a list of methods. I checked request.META but it doesn't have content_type either. I saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514077/get-request-body-as-string-in-django. It is exactly the same problem I face. Looks like this is the only way to get form data.