# displaying Data from multiple tables with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have been reading different posts with similar questions but I cannot get this figured out. I have a Job class that is linked to different tables such as Customer and Employee. The Data is coming back from the Database but I cannot get the Angular Table to display the linked classes. The suggestions have been to use different mods, restangular, angular-activerecord, ModelCore and this method
[angular js model relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530251/angular-js-model-relationships)
I am not sure the best route to take and what would be the simplest way of doing it.

```
app.factory('Job', function ($resource) {

return $resource('/api/apiJob/:id',
{ id: '@id' },
{ 'save': { method: 'POST' } },
{ 'update': { method: 'PUT' } },
{ 'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false } });
});
app.factory('jobFactory', function ($http) {
return {

    updateJob: function (job) {
        return $http.put('/api/apiJob/' + job.JobId, job);
    }
};
});
app.factory('Customer', function ($resource) {

return $resource('/api/apiCustomer/:id',
{ id: '@id' },
{ 'save': { method: 'POST' } },
{ 'update': { method: 'PUT' } },
{ 'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false } });
});
app.factory('customerFactory', function ($http) {
return {

    updateCustomer: function (customer) {
        return $http.put('/api/apiCustomer/' + customer.CustomerId, customer);
    }
};
});


'use strict';
 app.controller('JobCtrl', function ($scope, Job, $resource, $route, jobFactory,     notificationFactory, $http) {
////GET Jobs
$scope.jobArray = Job.query()

//New Job Modal
$scope.NewJobModal = function () {
    $('#NewJobModal').modal();
}
$scope.submitJob = function () {
    var data = {
        JobId: $scope.JobId,
        JobNumber: $scope.JobNumber,
        JobName: $scope.JobName,
        CustomerName: $scope.CustomerName,
        JobDescription: $scope.JobDescription,
        OriginalContract: $scope.OriginalContract,
        BillingDate: $scope.BillingDate,



    }
    $http.post('/api/apiJob/PostNewJob', data).success(function (data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    window.top.location.reload();
};
//End New Job Post

//Delete Job
$scope.deleteJob = function (job) {
    Job.delete({ id: job.JobId }, function () {

        if ($scope.jobArray.length === 1) {
            $scope.jobArray.splice(-1, 2);
        } else {
            $scope.jobArray.splice(job.JobId - 1, 2);
        }
        window.top.location.reload();
    });

};
//End Delete Job


    $scope.updateJob = function (job) {
    jobFactory.updateJob(job).success(successCallback).error(errorCallback);
};
$scope.job = [];

var successCallback = function (data, status, headers, config) {
    notificationFactory.success();

    return $('#editJobModal').modal('hide');
};
var errorCallback = function (data, status, headers, config) {
    notificationFactory.error(data.ExceptionMessage);
};

//End Edit Job


  }); //End Job Controller
```

What It looks like in the Browser Console

```
 0: {$id:1, JobId:1, JobNumber:2534, JobName:St.Lukes, JobDescription:Rebuilding Cafeteria,…}
 $id: "1"
 BalanceDue: 89654123
  BalanceToBill: 541256
  BillingDate: "2014-08-12T14:43:22.507"
   BillingForm: "Invoice"
  Budget: 854523658
  CertPayroll: true
  ChangeOrders: [{$id:4, ChangeOrderId:1, ChangeOrderNumber:7854,     ChangeOrderDate:2014-08-12T14:43:22.673,…}]
  ContractDate: "2014-08-12T14:43:22.507"
  Customers: [{$id:2, CustomerId:2, CustomerName:Grove at Wilcrest,    CustomerPhoneNumber:8327899667,…}]
  0: {$id:2, CustomerId:2, CustomerName:Grove at Wilcrest, CustomerPhoneNumber:8327899667,…}
  Employees: [{$id:3, EmployeeId:2, AccountName:Ham Sandwich, EmployeeFirstName:Scott,    EmployeeLastName:Willis,…}]
  JobAddress: "1234 Mason Rd"
  JobCity: "Katy"
  JobCost: 784556124
```

Updated Factory

```
app.factory('JobGet', function ($http, $q) {
var data = $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/apiJob'
})
return {
    query: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        setTimeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve(data)
        }, 2000);

        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
});
```

Network Response Tab

```
[{"$id":"1","JobId":1,"JobNumber":2534,"JobName":"St.Lukes","JobDescription":"Rebuilding Cafeteria","OriginalContract":1250210,"ContractDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.507","BillingDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.507","TotalCO":12502105,"RevisedContract":452136852,"Budget":854523658,"BillingForm":"Invoice","TESPM":"Frank Harvel","TESSuperintendent":"Rudy Sanchez","Status":"Active","MoreShit":"More shit goes here","TaxExempt":true,"CertPayroll":true,"JobCost":784556124,"RemainingBudget":96523145,"Profit":854125,"Percentage":45,"TotalBilled":45236554,"BalanceToBill":541256,"PaidToDate":0,"BalanceDue":89654123,"JobAddress":"1234 Mason Rd","JobCity":"Katy","JobState":"TX","JobZipcode":77493,"JobCounty":"Harris","JobPhone":2814569654,"JobFax":2814563251,"JobHidden":false,"Customers":[{"$id":"2","CustomerId":2,"CustomerName":"Grove at Wilcrest","CustomerPhoneNumber":8327899667,"CustomerFaxNumber":7134568547,"CustomerAddress":"56328 Richmond Ave","CustomerCity":"Houston","CustomerState":"TX","CustomerZipcode":77042,"CustomerWebsite":"grovewilcrest.com","CustomerOtherShit":"Other Shit Goes here","CustomerHidden":false,"CustomerPM":null,"CustomerAdmin":"Jane Miller","CustomerAccountant":"Betsy Sue","TESSuperintendent":null,"JobId":1,"Job":{"$ref":"1"}}],"Employees":[{"$id":"3","EmployeeId":2,"AccountName":"Ham Sandwich","EmployeeFirstName":"Scott","EmployeeLastName":"Willis","EmployeeTitle":"Admin","EmployeeCellPhone":2818567854,"EmployeeOfficePhone":7134527854,"EmployeeEmail":"testing@gmail.com","CompanyEmployeeId":12521,"EmployeeHidden":false,"EmployeeIsSuper":true,"EmployeeIsPM":true,"JobId":1,"Job":{"$ref":"1"}}],"ChangeOrders":[{"$id":"4","ChangeOrderId":1,"ChangeOrderNumber":7854,"ChangeOrderDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.673","ChangeOrderName":"Insert Name Here","ChangeOrderDescription":"It changed","ChangeOrderAmount":4000,"ChangeOrderApprovedDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.673","ChangeOrderApprovedAmount":3000,"ChangeOrderApprovedNumber":1,"ChangeOrderAttn":"Frank Harvel","ChangeOrderHidden":false,"JobId":1,"Job":{"$ref":"1"}}]},{"$id":"5","JobId":2,"JobNumber":12343,"JobName":"Katy Mills","JobDescription":"New Mall Bathrooms","OriginalContract":32623212,"ContractDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.507","BillingDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.507","TotalCO":12502105,"RevisedContract":452136852,"Budget":854523658,"BillingForm":"Invoice","TESPM":"Frank Harvel","TESSuperintendent":"Mike Hall","Status":"Active","MoreShit":"More shit goes here","TaxExempt":true,"CertPayroll":true,"JobCost":784556124,"RemainingBudget":96523145,"Profit":854125,"Percentage":45,"TotalBilled":45236554,"BalanceToBill":541256,"PaidToDate":0,"BalanceDue":89654123,"JobAddress":"1234 Mason Rd","JobCity":"Katy","JobState":"TX","JobZipcode":77493,"JobCounty":"Harris","JobPhone":2814456965,"JobFax":2814563225,"JobHidden":false,"Customers":[{"$id":"6","CustomerId":1,"CustomerName":"City Center","CustomerPhoneNumber":8327899667,"CustomerFaxNumber":7134568547,"CustomerAddress":"123453 HWY 6","CustomerCity":"Katy","CustomerState":"TX","CustomerZipcode":77493,"CustomerWebsite":"citycenter.com","CustomerOtherShit":"Other Shit Goes here","CustomerHidden":false,"CustomerPM":null,"CustomerAdmin":"Jane Miller","CustomerAccountant":"Betsy Sue","TESSuperintendent":null,"JobId":2,"Job":{"$ref":"5"}}],"Employees":[{"$id":"7","EmployeeId":3,"AccountName":"Ice Cream","EmployeeFirstName":"Aaron","EmployeeLastName":"Horstmann","EmployeeTitle":"Office Bitch","EmployeeCellPhone":2818567854,"EmployeeOfficePhone":7134527854,"EmployeeEmail":"aaron@gmail.com","CompanyEmployeeId":12521,"EmployeeHidden":false,"EmployeeIsSuper":true,"EmployeeIsPM":true,"JobId":2,"Job":{"$ref":"5"}}],"ChangeOrders":[{"$id":"8","ChangeOrderId":2,"ChangeOrderNumber":1823,"ChangeOrderDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.673","ChangeOrderName":"Insert Name Here","ChangeOrderDescription":"Work Orders","ChangeOrderAmount":4000,"ChangeOrderApprovedDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.673","ChangeOrderApprovedAmount":3000,"ChangeOrderApprovedNumber":2,"ChangeOrderAttn":"Rosie Sanchez","ChangeOrderHidden":false,"JobId":2,"Job":{"$ref":"5"}}]},{"$id":"9","JobId":3,"JobNumber":12398,"JobName":"City Center","JobDescription":"Remodeling Yard House","OriginalContract":56325412,"ContractDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.507","BillingDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.507","TotalCO":12502105,"RevisedContract":452136852,"Budget":854523658,"BillingForm":"Invoice","TESPM":"Frank Harvel","TESSuperintendent":"Shawn Saulnier","Status":"Active","MoreShit":"More shit goes here","TaxExempt":true,"CertPayroll":true,"JobCost":784556124,"RemainingBudget":96523145,"Profit":854125,"Percentage":45,"TotalBilled":45236554,"BalanceToBill":541256,"PaidToDate":0,"BalanceDue":89654123,"JobAddress":"1234 Mason Rd","JobCity":"Katy","JobState":"TX","JobZipcode":77493,"JobCounty":"Harris","JobPhone":2814256965,"JobFax":2814565325,"JobHidden":false,"Customers":[{"$id":"10","CustomerId":3,"CustomerName":"Twin Peaks","CustomerPhoneNumber":8327899667,"CustomerFaxNumber":7134568547,"CustomerAddress":"8473 Katy Fwy","CustomerCity":"Houston","CustomerState":"TX","CustomerZipcode":77043,"CustomerWebsite":"citycenter.com","CustomerOtherShit":"Other Shit Goes here","CustomerHidden":false,"CustomerPM":null,"CustomerAdmin":"Jane Miller","CustomerAccountant":"Betsy Sue","TESSuperintendent":null,"JobId":3,"Job":{"$ref":"9"}}],"Employees":[{"$id":"11","EmployeeId":1,"AccountName":"Not Sure","EmployeeFirstName":"Frank","EmployeeLastName":"Harvel","EmployeeTitle":"Manager","EmployeeCellPhone":2818567854,"EmployeeOfficePhone":7134527854,"EmployeeEmail":"texas45@gmail.com","CompanyEmployeeId":12521,"EmployeeHidden":false,"EmployeeIsSuper":true,"EmployeeIsPM":false,"JobId":3,"Job":{"$ref":"9"}}],"ChangeOrders":[{"$id":"12","ChangeOrderId":3,"ChangeOrderNumber":45324,"ChangeOrderDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.673","ChangeOrderName":"Insert Name Here","ChangeOrderDescription":"It changed again","ChangeOrderAmount":4000,"ChangeOrderApprovedDate":"2014-08-12T14:43:22.673","ChangeOrderApprovedAmount":3000,"ChangeOrderApprovedNumber":3,"ChangeOrderAttn":"Travis Dillard","ChangeOrderHidden":false,"JobId":3,"Job":{"$ref":"9"}}]}]
```

Comment: I guess that the first step is to check if the response from the server has the Job with all it's data populated. If it is ok, then we need to check if how is your view's binding. Please check it out and share some of your code, perhaps if you made a plunkr with some example data it could be easier to help you.

Comment: Will get on it. thanks!

Comment: ok, I put together the plunkr with the related files. not sure how to get it to work with the json data. but i did get it setup as my project looks. note: the EmployeeController, EmployeeDataAdapter, IEmployeeInterface, apiEmployeeController is what the other classes look like,("ChangeOrders","Customer"). I also put the json data from my browser console. http://plnkr.co/edit/BCuQDkA3lanhTKg81fzA?p=preview

Comment: great job! about the json data, can you grab the response from the network tab in google chrome and paste it there? The one that is currently there appears to be the result of a console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is a work in progress. Your code is very large and to solve this I removed a lot o noise from your plunkr, I left there only what's essential to make it work and only the code involved in it.

***[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PuC55EhFDZQULI15AvlX?p=preview)***

First thing to notice, on your `JobController` you are doing:

```
////GET Jobs
$scope.jobArray = Job.query();
```

This worked on previous versions of angular, on the current version there is no automatic promise unwrapping anymore, so you must use the `then` function:

```
////GET Jobs
Job.query().then(function(retrievedData){
    $scope.jobArray = retrievedData;
});
```

Notice that on the plunkr I "mocked" the returning of data using `$q` and a timeout, I actually cleaned the json leaving only the properties that are used on the table, just to make it simpler, you don't need to do that on your code ok? Just keep that part as it is.

Maybe you'll have to modify it just to resolve the promise with the returned data, but this is up to you, the important thing is to return a promise from your `query()` method and resolve it.

On the HTML I noticed that you are binding the customer name like this:

```
<td>{{job.Customers.CustomerName}}</td>
```

But on your Json, the `Customers` property is an array of customers, so you either return one customer from your api or bind it like this:

```
<td>{{job.Customers[0].CustomerName}}</td>
```

I also noticed that there are a lot of jQuery references on your controllers like this:
    $('#editJobModal').modal();

This is not recommended and I don't think it will work at all, when dealing with the DOM, always use directives and comunicate with them using bindings, thats the angular way.

Well after all this, my plunkr is showing the table with the 2 fake customers from the Json. Now I suggest you to study that code and apply those principles to your app.

I hope I could help or at least point you at the right direction.

Comment: I added the updated factory I put together. The Data is coming back like last time but nothing is displaying. I used $http instead of $resource, what am i doing wrong?