# How to provide a collection of resources that contains links/ids to another resource with an Angular 2 service?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, angular, angular2-services

I have a collection of users. Each user has a `cards` array, which is composed of the `id`s of the cards that the user chose.

`user.cards = [10, 12, 24, 31]`

I want to have the 10 cards that are the most chosen by users.

I have `user.service.js` and `card.service.js`, which I guess are DAOs. `card.service.js` looks something like this (used plain `Promises` for simplicity).

```
(function(app) {
    app.CardService = ng.core.Injectable({}).Class({
        constructor: function() {},
        getCards: function() {
            return Promise.resolve(app.cards)
        },
        getCard: function(cardId) {
            return Promise.resolve(app.cards.get(cardId));
        },
        getTop10Cards: function() {
            // How would I go about doing this method?
        }
    })
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Logically, I would need the list of all the users, collect their `cardIds` and aggregate them to find the most used cards. But should `CardService` use `UserService` (as an injection)? Or is using a DAO in another DAO the wrong way to go about it? Should I have a separate collection that contains the links between each models (like a joint table)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help myself deal with this client-side problem, I investigated on what the back-end resources would look like. I came up with something similar than "[How to handle many-to-many relationships in a RESTful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324547/how-to-handle-many-to-many-relationships-in-a-restful-api/6333146#6333146)".

These are what my API endpoints will potentially look like: `/users`, `/cards`, `/cards/{cardId}/votes`. `/cards/{cardId}/votes` contains resources that define the relationship between the users and the cards they have chosen.

In the code, I am indeed injecting `vote.service.js` inside `card.service.js`. When I `GET` the cards, I also compose them with their subset of `votes`. See "[angular js model relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530251/angular-js-model-relationships/14530508#14530508)" for more information.

I hope this will help anyone that will come across this question.

Cheers!