# using memoize function with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I am trying to cache the result from an ajax call using `memoize` function from `Underscore.js`. I am not sure of my implementation. Also how to retrieve back the cached result data using the key. Below is my implementation:

Javascript code:

```
var cdata = $http
.get(HOST_URL + "/v1/report/states")
.success(function(data) {
    //put the result in the angularJs scope object. 
    $scope.states = data;
});

//store the result in the cache.
var cachedResult = _.memoize(
    function() {
        return cdata;
    }, "states");
```

Is my usage of memoize to store the result of ajax is correct. Also once it is put in cache, how to retrieve based on the key. i.e 'states'.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let us understand how `_.memoize` works, it takes a function which needs to be memoized as first argument and caches the result of the function return for given parameter. Next time if the memoized function is invoked with same argument it will use cached result and the execution time for the function can be avoided. So it is very important to reduce the computation time.

As mentioned, the above fibonaci function it memoized works perfectly fine as the argument has a primitive type.

The problem occurs when you have to memoize a function which accepts an object. To solve this, `_.memoize` accepts an optional argument `hashFunction` which will be used to hash the input. This way you can uniquely identify your objects with your own hash functions.

The default implementation of `_.memoize` (using the default hash function) returns the first argument as it is - in the case of JavaScript it will return `[Object object]`.

So for e.g.

```
var fn = function (obj){ some computation here..}
var memoizedFn = _.memoize(fn);

memoizedFn({"id":"1"}) // we will get result, and result is cahced now

memoizedFn({"id":"2"}) // we will get cached result which is wrong
```

why default has function in _.memoize is function(x) {return x}

the problem can be avoided by passing a hash function

```
_.memoize(fn, function(input){return JSON.stringify(input)});
```

This was a real help for me when I was using _.memoize for a function that was working on arrays arguments.

Hope this helps many people in their work.

Comment: Fixed some grammar mistakes and added some additional information.

Answer (score 5):

[`_.memoize`](http://underscorejs.org/#memoize) takes a function:

```
var fibonacci = _.memoize(function(n) {
  return n < 2 ? n: fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
});
```

You should understand that this is just an extra wrapper function that makes function that you pass it as an argument smarter( Adds extra mapping object to it ).

In example above function that computes fibonacci number is wrapped around with `_.memoize`. So on every function call (`fibonacci(5)` or `fibonacci(55555)`) passed argument matched to return value so if you need to call one more time `fibonacci(55555)` it doesn't need to compute it again. It just fetches that value from that mapping object that `_.memoize` provided internally.

Comment: **WARNING**: The example has an **infinite recursion!** when calling `fibonacci(x)`

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Angular.js's `$http`, you probably just want to pass `{cache : true}` as a second parameter to the `get` method.

To store values using key value pairs, you may want to use [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache), as described in other answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/how-to-cache-an-http-get-service-in-angularjs). Basically:

```
var cache = $cacheFactory('cacheId');
cache.put('states', 'value');
cache.get('states');
```