# Is it possible to memoize each data output when the argument gets changed

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, memoization

I want to cache each output of a function. That means once it's calculated for a particular input, the next call should take it from the cache.

If fresh calculation it can be calculated again.

Can `_.memoize` do that?

Comment: Please create [mcve] to show effort and code

Comment: add a variable to function itself and change it every time you call it

Comment: Yes, you can find a complete answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902019/using-memoize-function-with-underscore-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using memoize function with underscore.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902019/using-memoize-function-with-underscore-js)