# Avoid too many requests in Sails.js + AngularJS (caching HTTP requests)

Tags: angularjs, module, httprequest, sails.js

I'm using Sails.js as base for my project, and so far I'm trying to modularize every UI element using AngularJS.

Although I think this approach is good because it allows me to reuse my code as much as possible, in the end I will have to make many HTTP requests to the server because each module doesn't share data with the others.

So, what would be a solution to mitigate the number of requests and share the data among all controllers?

I have thought of 2 different solutions:

- Populate views from the back-end reducing the amount of data the AngularJS controllers are requesting.
- Request data dynamically using sockets and cache the commonly used queries.

Comment: had you thought of caching the data in an angular service?

Comment: I really didn't know about that! I'll look for more informations about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that you can cache HTTP requests in AngularJS using `$cacheFactory` (documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache)).

An easy way to do it is the following one:

```
$http({
    url : '/your/path',
    method : 'POST',
    cache : true
})
.success(function (data) {
    data;
})
```

More informations can be found on [coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/40axlq) and on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/how-to-cache-an-http-get-service-in-angularjs).

Answer (score 1):

An [angular service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) is typically used to share data between controllers. Here's a simple example of what that may look like. Note it will only make a request to get data the first time, after that it will use the stored value.

```
app.factory('dataService', function () {
    var service = {};
    var data;

    service.getData = function () {
        if (!data) {
            //populate data via http get or whatever
        }
        return data;
    }

    return service;
});
```

This service can then be injected into any controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [angular-cache and angular-data](http://angular-data.pseudobry.com/)?
It's both a wrapper to the built in angular data communication layer, as well as a client side data store.