# How to reuse controller for different views in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am receiving object data from one JSON request, similar to this:

```
{
  "slides": [
    {
      "image": "http://lorempizza.com/380/240",
      "title": "Slide aa",
      "description": "I owe you the description"
    },{
      "image": "http://lorempizza.com/380/240",
      "title": "Slide bb",
      "description": "I owe you the description"
    }
  ],
  "title": "Interesting object",
  "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
}
```

I want to use *two different views*. One for the slides and another one for the title and description of the object, everything on the same page. Why? Because I'm using ui views to display them.

**index.html**

```
<div ui-view="slider"></div><!-- Here is the slider -->
<main ui-view role="main"></main><!-- Here is title and desc -->
```

The problem is here:

**slider.html**

```
<div ng-controller="InterestingObjectCtrl">
    <!-- Display slider -->
</div>
```

**main.html**

```
<div ng-controller="InterestingObjectCtrl">
    <!-- Display title and desc -->
</div>
```

**InterestingObjectCtrl.js**

```
InterestingService.get()
    .success(function(data) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.interestingObject = data;
        });
      });
    })
```

The `InterestingObjectCtrl` controller will load twice the same JSON making useless HTTP requests.

What would be the right way or "angular way" to solve this?

---

Setting a flag (like `if ($scope.requestAlreadyMade) return;`) will definitely won't work.

The HTTP requests may not be a big deal [caching the `$http` service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14117653/1505348), but that is far from the point of this problem.

Calling the controller as a wrapper, like the following example, will make it be loaded from *every page* on the website, which is even worst.

```
<div ng-controller="InterestingObjectCtrl">
  <div ui-view="slider"></div><!-- Here is the slider -->
  <main ui-view role="main"></main><!-- Here is title and desc -->
</div>
```

Comment: Meanwhile, take a look at angular ui router's way of solving this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
         <div ui-view="slider"></div><!-- Here is the slider -->
         <main ui-view role="main"></main><!-- Here is title and desc -->
    </div>
```

load data once in MainCtrl and breadcast it to child controllers:

```
InterestingService.get()
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.$broadcast('dataloaded', data);
    });
```

InterestingObjectCtrl.js

```
$scope.$on('dataloaded', function (data) {
// do what you want
});
```

Comment: I will be forced to load the controller on every page of the web site. That is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Lucio i thought you asked for solution for "The InterestingObjectCtrl controller will load twice the same JSON". With MainCtrl you will load it only once.