# Angularjs promise blocking solutions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, block, promise

I need a function which will return a boolean value. The first time this function is called, it should load the value from an async service (that returns a promise) and then cache it. Subsequent calls to this function should return the cached value. Problem is the caller of this function should be blocked until it gets a value. Whats the best solution in this case? Should the function return a promise either way (i.e whether its cached or not), and just put everything that needs to be blocked inside promise.then(). And if thats a good solution, how do I return a promise in either case (e.g. when its cached or not)?

---

Below is some code to better illustrate the problem:

```
function isSomethingStored() {

    if(getFromBrowserStorage() != null) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(true);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    var promise = ThirdParty.getSomethingThroughAjax();
    promise.then(function(theSomething) {
        addToBrowserStorage(theSomething);
        return true; 
    });
    return promise;

}

function caller() {
    var promise = isSomethingStored();
    promise.then(function(isReady) {
       //we can continue
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, it should always return a promise, for consistency. But the functionality is already built into angular, just use angular's cache

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/how-to-cache-an-http-get-service-in-angularjs and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http (search for cache)

Comment: $http.get(url, { cache: true}).success(...);

Comment: post what you have tried, your code, where you're stuck and people will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it *should* always return a promise unless there is another consideration preventing it from doing so. This is for consistency - if a method *might* be asynchronous it is best practice to always treat it as asynchronous so you won't get funky race conditions later on.

Since you can't block anyway, and the workarounds are hacky - I think it probably fits your problem optimally anyway. Simply put all reliant code in a `then`.