# How to store data in angularjs for pagination and send it as response

Tags: angularjs

My requirement is I have to store large amount of data using angular for pagination. This data will come from server side. How can we do it using angular?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache data you can do it in a number of ways.  Two of approaches are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/how-to-cache-an-http-get-service-in-angularjs):-

1. Use $http inbuild cache  that's simple (details in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/how-to-cache-an-http-get-service-in-angularjs) above).

   $http.get(url, { cache: true}).success(...);
2. Use $[cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)  (details in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/how-to-cache-an-http-get-service-in-angularjs) above)
3. Simply cache it inside your service:-

Service:-

```
    var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp",[]);

    todoApp.factory('dbService', ['$q','$http',function ($q , $http) {  
    var service ={};
    service.localCache = {hasdata:false,data:{},lastLoaded:new Date()};

        service.getUrl = function (urlToGet,burstCache) {
            var svc=this;

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if ((!burstCache)&&(svc.localCache)&&(svc.localCache.hasdata)) {
                    console.log('resolve from local cache');
                    return(svc.localCache.data);
            }else{
            var responsePromise = $http.get(urlToGet);

            responsePromise.success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                svc.localCache={}; 
                svc.localCache.hasdata=true; 
                svc.localCache.data=data; 
                svc.localCache.lastLoaded= new Date(); 
                deferred.resolve(data); 
                console.log('resolve from ajax') });

            responsePromise.error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                deferred.reject({ error: "Ajax Failed", errorInfo: data }); svc.localCache={}; });
            }
            return (deferred.promise);
        }

        return service;
        }]);
```

Controller:-

```
 todoApp.controller("ToDoCtrl",['$scope','$timeout','dbService',function($scope, $timeout, dbService)
    {
        $scope.todo={};
      //Fetches the data from server. 'true' means burstCache
      $timeout(function(){
       dbService.getUrl('/api/userdata',true).then(function(resp){
        $scope.todo=resp;
       });},1);

    //ReLoads the data from cache
    $scope.reLoad=function(){
        $scope.todo={};
        $timeout(function() {$scope.todo=dbService.getUrl('/api/userdata');},1000);

    };
    }]);
```