# How to cache http in Angular until parameters changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to cache some http until parameters used in url change:

```
app.factory('dataService', function ($http,$rootScope) {
    return {
        getData: function () {
            return $http.get(rest.getData
           + $rootScope.number + "/" + $rootScope.blb
            ).then(function (result) {
                return result.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

So, when $rootScope.number changes in controller, I need to call http again, until then it should be cached. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's $http has [cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching) built in. Set cache as `true` in your `$http` request options:

```
$http.get(url, {cache: true}).then(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache data you can do it in a number of ways.

You can cache it inside your service also.

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314323/how-to-store-data-in-angularjs-for-pagination-and-send-it-as-response/28316656#28316656) is post which should help you.