# Create Multiple Dynamic views inherited from single template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating mobile chat app in angularjs.

It has lets say 100 userlist.  If user presses on some userlist, it takes to next view(chat view). So, as user presses on userlist . I want to create a dynamic chat view of that user based on his userId.
One way of doing this is - I define the route like this 'chat/:userId'. Then access the userId. Also messages of particular user is coming from server. And new chat messages is appended to the view.

I have doubt that if user open the same view again it will load the basic template again because view is changed . It will again send the request to server again. It should not.
For clearing the question, In mobile jquery (http://iflychat.com/drupalchat/mobile-chat)
If user opens the view lets say public chatroom , It only takes load time once. If we again come back to this same view, it loads instantly. It creates the view based on url.  Is this kind of functionality possible in angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

Angular has an $http cache that could help you accomplish something similar:

```
 $http.get(url, { cache: true}).success(...);
```

There are also a few other ways using the same cache.

Here is a very detailed post [How to cache an http get service in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/how-to-cache-an-http-get-service-in-angularjs)

Thanks,
Paul