# AngularJS enums provided by server

Tags: angularjs, enums

I need to assign department to an employee in angularJS application.
I created API resource on server side which returns JSON array of possible values.

```
[
  {"id":0,"name":"human resources"},
  {"id":1,"name":"public relations"},
  {"id":2,"name":"development"}
]
```

And my Employee resource works with IDs of department, like so..

```
{
  employeeId: 1,
  firstName: "Adam",
  lastName: "Abrons",
  departmentId: 2
}
```

I want to use those values in angular filter for viewing employee and for ngOptions directive for editing employee.

Since those enum values are pretty much stable, how do I load them once and keep them on client side until user leaves the website?

Comment: I personally use enum from mongoose schema, http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-enum

Comment: You load them and store the http promise in a variable of a service. You get this promise from the service every time you need it.

Comment: I've used html localStorage for this kinda thing before, however you can also use angular.js cache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **build it cache** feature in `$http` module

```
$http.get('/api/enums', {cache: true}).success(function(enums){
});
```

In addition, you can also wrap it up as a `service`

```
angular.module('app').service('enumService', function ($http) {

    return {
        getEnums: getEnums
    };

    function getEnums(){
        return $http.get('/api/enums', {cache: true});
    }
});
```

---

Other way **using a promise** (credit to [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)'s comment)

```
angular.module('app').service('enumService', EnumService);

function EnumService($http) {

    var getEnumsPromise = $http.get('/api/enums');

    return {
        getEnums: getEnums
    };

    function getEnums(){
        return getEnumsPromise;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simply use `var result = $http.get('/api/enums');`, and return this result from `getEnums()`