# Bind http request data to another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nav that looks something like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="admin-side-nav" ng-controller="AdminNav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="/admin/leaderboard/{{gameId}}">Leaderboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/newsFeed/{{gameId}}">News Feed</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am then using routes which load a template and with an ajax request to get data to put in the template. The returned request has an id in it that I would like to bind to `gameId`, but I can't figure out how it is done.

Here is the javascript to do this:

```
var console = angular.module('Console', ["ngRoute", "highcharts-ng"]);

console.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/admin/:gameid', {
        templateUrl: 'admin/game.html',
        controller: 'Game'
    });
}).controller("Game", function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("http://admin.gmserver.net/mypage").success(function(data){
        $scope.games = data;
        $scope.gameId = data._id;
    });
}).controller("AdminNav", function($scope, $location){
    $scope.isActive = function(viewLocation){
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };
});
```

I would like to bind this line from the `Game` controller `$scope.gameId = data._id;` to the value in the `AdminNav` controller. How can I pass the data from the `Game` controller to the `AdminNav` controller?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js

Comment: how about moving the `$http` out to a `service` so that it can be used in any `controller`? it might be a good idea to `cache` it too like this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/how-to-cache-an-http-get-service-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use either:

1) `$rootScope.gameId = data._id`

2) A service that adds and gets the value

3) a $broadcast to $on

4) a localstorage call

`$localstorage.setObject('gameId', data._id);`

and in the AdminNav Controller:

```
`var yourNewValue = $localstorage.getObject('gameId');
```

See http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/ for defining $localstorage