# Cache Google Maps client-side geocoding results

Tags: javascript, cordova, caching, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I have a PhoneGap application runnning on Android and iOS that currently geocodes a list of addresses. However, if the amount of addresses in the list is too great, the geocoder returns `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`. Is it possible to cache geocoding results on the client so that I am not geocoding the same list of addresses every time, perhaps using LocalStorage on the device?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a http service over the $http one (without havung to use de $httpProvider). I'm actually developping a reusable one if you want to take some inspiration : https://github.com/ivangabriele/angular-cordova-router.

It's based on LocalStorage. But you can also directly use the original [$http caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching).

Eventually you can also couple that with the [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory).

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/how-to-cache-an-http-get-service-in-angularjs) that can help you if you prefers 2nd or 3rd option.