# Angular JS $http request - caching success response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've got a simple dataFactory that retrieves some posts:

```
dataFactory.getPosts = function () {
    if (this.httpPostsData == null) {
        this.httpPostsData = $http.get("http://localhost/matImms/wp-json/posts?type=journey&filter[posts_per_page]=-1&filter[order]=ASC&filer[orderby]=date")
            .success(function (posts) {

            })
            .error(function (posts) {
                console.log('Unable to load post data: ' + JSON.stringify(posts));
            });
    }

    return (this.httpPostsData);
}
```

The controller calls the factory and I understand that the posts are promises -so there is some stuff done on success and some stuff that is done anyway. This works fine.

```
.controller('CardsCtrl', function($scope, dataFactory,
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $stateParams) {

    var parentID = $stateParams.parentID;
    var keyIDNumber = $stateParams.keyID;

    $scope.card = [];

    var httpcall = dataFactory.getPosts()
        .success(function (posts) {
            $scope.card = dataFactory.getChildPosts(parentID, posts, keyIDNumber);

            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
        });

    // do other stuff ......
});
```

However, I'm now trying to cache the post data - but when the controller is called a second time it returns the error .success is not a function. I assume the is because the posts have already been returned - but how do I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not returning the `$http.get`, you're returning the promise after `.success` and `.error` have already been handled.

You can either change the controller to call `.then` on the return, or change the service to just return the `$http.get` (remove the `.success` and `.error`) and handle them in the controller.

If you change the controller to use `.then` you'll also need to update the `.success` function in the service to `return posts;`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `cache` option to true in your `$http` call? Like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14117744/1283740

Maybe something like this...

```
angular.module('foo', [])

.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function($http){

  var dataFactory = {
          getPosts: getPosts
      };

  function getPosts(){

    var url = "http://localhost/matImms/wp-json/posts?type=journey&filter[posts_per_page]=-1&filter[order]=ASC&filer[orderby]=date"

    return $http({ cache: true, url: url, method: 'GET'})
      .error(function (posts) {
        console.log('Unable to load post data: ' + JSON.stringify(posts));
      });

  };

   return dataFactory;

}])
```