# Is there a simple way to only call API once in directive when used multiple times in view

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-http

I have made a directive that makes a dropdown and populates it from an API. It works. However when I used this directive multiple times in a view it makes multiple calls to the API to populate the dropdown.

So I was wondering if there was some simple way to avoid that. The not so simple way would be to put the $http into a service that does caching somehow.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('dropdown', function() {
    return {
        // omitted...
        controller: function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("...")...;
        }
    };
});
```

**View**

```
<dropdown></dropdown>
<dropdown></dropdown>
```

Comment: $http.get("....",{cache:true})

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cache an http get service in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/how-to-cache-an-http-get-service-in-angularjs)

Comment: You could do the request via a service and control how many times it gets sent within the service logic.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a service to handle your $http requests and it will also allow you to cache data.

In this particular case you will keep your data in an object in the service and each time you load the directive and call the service method *getMyData(blah)* you will check if the data exists already in the object and cancel the call to the API, otherwise perform the $http.get.