# how to handle JSON file loading with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

I have a few controllers that call the method `getData()` from a service.
In order to not do extra http calls for the same json file, i'm using something like this:

```
QuizApp.service('quizService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var quizService = {},
        quizData;

    quizService.getData = function() {
        return quizData ? quizData : quizData = $http.get('quiz.json');
    };

    return quizService;
}]);
```

...but things don't work properly if I do it like that (the data is used to populate a slider and a thumbnail gallery with angular-slick and some problems arise. For now it maybe doesn't matter, I just want to know if the code above makes sense).

On the other hand, if I write `getData()` like this:

```
QuizApp.service('quizService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var quizService = {},
        quizData;

    quizService.getData = function() {
        quizData = $http.get('quiz.json');
        return quizData;
    };

    return quizService;
}]);
```

... which will do various http requests for the same json file (doesn't look like a good practice to me), everything works fine and the slick angular gallery works properly. But not 100% of the times though: kind of randomly things don't work well too (same symptoms. I might describe them but again, I don't think that's the point here)

So, in general, regardless of the context, which one of those versions of `getData()` looks good and which doesn't and why?

*UPDATE*

As Mark pointed out, Angular has a built in cache, but it's set to false by default. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/how-to-cache-an-http-get-service-in-angularjs) is a post and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is the documentation.

If I cache the result of the http request though I get the same problem (I'm not describing it here) I was getting with my second option, and it has apparently nothing to do with that.

Actually, it seems that if I repeat the http request two times (as in my second snippet of code) things work by chance (90% of the time?).

So, by caching the result, at least I get a consistent result, which means in this case that the slick-angular thing won't work properly (never) and I have to look for a solution somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but did not `$http.get` should return `promise`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular $http has a built in cache, which you could make use of here. You can cache all $http requests, which is probably a bad idea, or specific ones.

On a very simple level, this should work for you

```
quizService.getData = function() {
  return $http.get('quiz.json', {cache: true}).then(quizData => {
    return quizData;
  });
};
```

You can find out more in the [Angular docs for $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)